# Deleting posts/questions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I'm a beginner working through a rails tutorial. I've been assigned to create a model and a controller for Questions, to create/view/index all the questions asked. I also need to be able to delete questions. I got some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815292/rails-unable-to-destroy-post) about what's needed in the controller, but I'm not sure as to how to implement the function in the views. I would like to include the option to delete the question in the edit page. Any pointers will be much appreciated--many thanks!

My controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body))
    if @question.save
      flash[:notice] = "Question was saved."
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end 
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if @question.update_attributes(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body))
      flash[:notice] = "Question was updated"
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.destroy
    redirect_to questions_path
    flash[:notice] = "The question has been deleted."
  end
end
```

Show view:

```
<h1><%= @question.title %></h1>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_question_path(@question), class: 'btn btn-success' %>

<p><%= @question.body %></p>
```

Edit view:

```
<h1>Edit and Update Question</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Guidelines for questions</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Stay on topic.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for @question do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.  To include a delete link in the `index` view (not shown?), you can use `link_to`:

```
  <%= link_to "delete", @question, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Where `@question` represents one of the questions in your `index` view.

Comment: Sure glad to help a fellow traveler